# Extract specific contents from text using python and Tesseract OCR

Tags: python, image, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using tesseract OCR to extract text from image file [image].

Below is the sample text I got from my Image:

```
Certificate No. Certificate Issued Date Acoount Reference Unique Doc. Reference IN-KA047969602415880 18-Feb-2016 01:39 PM NONACC(FI)/kakfscI08/BTM LAYOUT/KA-BA SUBIN-KAKAKSFCL0858710154264833O
```

How can I extract Certificate No. from this? Any hint or solution will help me here.

Answer (score 1):

If the certificate number is always in the structure it is given here (2 letters, hyphen, 17 digits) you can use `regex`:

```py
import regex as re

# i took the entire sequence originally but this is just an example
sequence = 'Reference IN-KA047969602415880 18-Feb-2016 01:39'
re.search('[A-Z]{2}-.{17}', seq).group()
#'IN-KA047969602415880'
```

`.search` searches for a specific pattern you dictate, and `.group()` return the first result (in this case there would be only one). You can search for anything like this in a given string, I suggest a review of `regex` [here](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter7/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to make it dynamic, like looking for some solutions other than using Indexing or character Length.

Comment: @RajeevSrivastava There is no indexing here, the search is for regular expressions. `[A-Z]{2}-.{17}` means an expression that contains `{2}` characters of type `[A-Z]`, a hyphen, then any (`.`) `{17}` characters, which should match the general structure of a certificate number. You can make the search as dynamic as you like and alternative search expressions, `regex` is capable of plenty.

Comment: In the above example which I posted along with ''IN-KA047969602415880'' it also matches 'KA-BA SUBIN-KAKAKSFC' @Ronny Efronny

Comment: @RajeevSrivastava That would be becasue `.{17}` refers to any 17 characters at all, including spaces. Try instead doing `[A-Z]{2}-\S{17}`, where `\S` means any non-space character. Again I emphasize that to use this method you must only find a structure for the certificate number and search for that, but it has to be specific enough to not accidentally catch other things (like in this case, where a space was one of the 17 characters).

Answer (score 1):

Before throwing the image into Tesseract OCR, it's important to preprocess the image to remove noise and smooth the text. Here's a simple approach using OpenCV

- Convert image to grayscale
- Otsu's threshold to obtain binary image
- Gaussian blur and invert image

---

After converting to grayscale, we Otsu's threshold to get a binary image

[image]

From here we give it a slight blur and invert the image to get our result

[image]

Results from Pytesseract

> Certificate No. : IN-KA047969602415880

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image = cv2.imread('1.png',0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (3,3), 0)
result = 255 - blur 

data = pytesseract.image_to_string(result, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```